# Why I cannot generate multiple files twice or more in same folders in nodejs

Tags: node.js, filestream, fs

I'm trying to generate multiple files in same folder as follow, but problem is I could be able to generate multiple files in same folder first time. And trying to generate second time, rendering is successfully done but files are not created in that folder again. At that time, I need to create another folder to generate it. Why I cannot generate multiple files twice or more in same folders in nodejs? Please let me know there is some missing in my codes.

```
const generateObjectCode = async (objectCount) => {
    let objectSegment = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < objectCount; i++){
        objectSegment.push(generateObjectCodeString(`ppshein-${i}`));
    }
    return await Promise.all(objectSegment).then(data => {
        return data;
    });
}

const generateObjectImage = async (folderName, fileName, base64Data) => {
    return await fs.writeFile(`./${folderName}/${fileName}.png`, base64Data, 'base64');
}

const generateObjectCodeString = (objectSegment) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        BlahLibrary.generateBase64(objectSegment, function (err, url) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(url);
            }
        });
    });
}

generateObjectCode(10).then(data => {
    let i = 0;
    data = data.map(entry => {
        i++;
        generateObjectImage('folder1', i, entry);
    });
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('err ' + JSON.stringify(err));
});
```

Comment: If the `fs` you're using is the standard `fs` module, then it doesn't support promises - hence you shouldn't `await fs.writeFile` and instead provide a callback and check for possible errors that lock your files somehow ?

Comment: @StockOverflaw I'm using like `const fs = require('mz/fs');`

Comment: Try to `return Promise.all(data.map(entry => generateObjectImage('folder1', i++, entry)));` instead of `data = data.map...`, and add a `.then` block with a log to check everything finished properly before calling the process again ?